# Kotlin's URL.readText() crashes when I turn my phone's internet off

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

I am doing an HTTP GET request using Kotlin's `URL.readText()` in an *AsyncTask*. I'm not making the common mistake of networking in the UI thread, yet my app still experiences crashes.

If I start my app with internet off or turn internet off during operation, it crashes the next time I indirectly trigger a GET request with user input. What is a good way to do a "safe" GET request that just returns an empty String for example instead of crashing?

I separated each call into its own line to make sure it was `readText()` causing the crash, and not for example the GoogleMap I also use. I also checked the URL object and it is not null. The app does not request any permissions.

---

Task:

```
class MyTask(map : GoogleMap, url : String) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    val mMap = map;
    val mURL = url;

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String {
        return URL(mURL).readText()
    }

    ... (more code) ...
}
```

UI Thread:

```
MyTask(mMap, url).execute()
```

Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
```

Comment: `AsyncTask` is deprecated. Working purely with a `URL` for Internet access is fairly ancient. OkHttp would allow you to avoid both of those. However, exceptions fairly intrinsic to how these sorts of APIs work, so wrap your I/O in a `try`/`catch` block.

Comment: Just for reference, doing it this way was recommended in multiple StackOverflow answers

Comment: What Exception class would I catch?

Comment: "What Exception class would I catch?" -- I typically catch anything that I can reasonably deal with. That might just be `Exception`, or possibly `Throwable` (a supertype of `Exception`).

Comment: Okay, makes sense, I guess the strange error message just threw me off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CommonsWare's suggestion of catching an Exception works for me, I thought the "fatal" meant it cannot be caught.

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String {
    return try {
        URL(mURL).readText()
    } catch (ex : Exception) {
        "null"
    }
}
```

Even shorter:

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String =
    try { URL(mURL).readText() } catch (ex : Exception) { "null" }
```

Comment: Here, "FATAL EXCEPTION" just means that it *wasn't* caught, not that it cannot be caught.

Comment: Thanks - that was it.  Why does the error not print a stacktrace when uncaught though?